# Reuse NioEventLoopGroup after shutdown of netty stack

Tags: java, garbage-collection, netty

Is it good practice to reuse `NioEventLoopGroup` after shutdown of `netty` stack?

Here is some background:

We are running out of memory off-heap when establishing `netty` connection soon after connection-loss (we reconnect `netty` and recreate the stack right after connection was lost). We are running 32-bit java hence the virtual memory space is limited.

Doing a `gc` right before establishing new connection seems to fix this issue by cleaning up memory off-heap. However, doing an explicit `System.gc` is bad practice.

We suspect that the bulk of off-heap memory is referenced by the `NioEventLoopGroup` hence we are trying to reuse if for the new connection. However we are concerned that there may still be tasks queued up on the `NioEventLoopGroup` from previous run.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the developers have stated that it is good practice to reuse the `EventLoopGroup`.

See:

> Re-use EventLoopGroup if you can!

http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-facebook-eng-netty/slides.html#25.0

or:

> Usually, it's just fine to create a single event loop group instance
>   and reuse it for all channels.

https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/639